# NSString Converting into a doubleValue after extracting NSString from UIPicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, uipickerview

I have :

```
    NSInteger dollarrow = [ValuesPicker selectedRowInComponent:kDollar];

    NSString *dollar = [dollarlist objectAtIndex:dollarrow];

   double converteddollar=0;
```

I want to do a for loop on this and get the value in double , I am trying this :

```
    for(dollar=1;dollar<=99;dollar++)
    {
    converteddollar = converteddollar + 2;
    }
```

Now the dollar contains NSString how do I convert into double to do the operation successfully and then

```
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%0.2f",converteddollar];
```

I am getting warnings and the app is crashing .. How can I correct it . 
I am learning Objective C please help .
Thankyou .
Sorry I did not want == i just wanted to use =

Comment: What warnings do you get? And what are you trying to do with this loop?

Comment: Your loop is dong nothing... forget the warnings for now and fix your code's logic first.

Comment: Error:Lvalue required as increment operand 
if I do [dollar doubleValue]+1 there are no errors but it crashes ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop is wrong. Are you really want '=='? I guess you want only '='. Can't you use something like this? (I'm just giving an example to point the mistakes in loop. Your requirement may be something different. And also I have not compiled the code, don't have mac with me right now. So you may get some minor mistake)

```
double sum = 0

for (NSInteger i = 1; i <= 99; i++) {
    sum += 2;  // or whatever you need here
}

NSString *convertedStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf", sum];
```

Comment: the 'i' in my case is an NSString which was extracted from the UIPicker.

Comment: convert it to a int. NSInteger i = [str intValue];

Answer (score 0):

Lots of errors...

```
NSInteger dollarrow = [ValuesPicker selectedRowInComponent:kDollar];
```

The `selectedRowInComponent:` method is a member method. Not a static one. You need to call it on an **instance**.

`==` is a comparison operator. What you want is certainly an assignment, with a single `=`sign.

You declare a pointer to a NSString object. But it's not initialized.
You should also use a temporary double variable for your loop.

I don't understand what your loop is supposed to do. Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: well basically I want to get the dollar value from the selected picker value .. then want to use the value to set the converteddollar to +2 of the value which it was previously , assume that the converteddollar value as of now is 0 .thankyou

Answer (score 0):

`NSString *dollar = [dollarlist objectAtIndex:dollarrow];`

`double converteddollar = [dollar doubleValue];` should work (no need for you `for` loop)